# Sum values in clojure and add totals to dataset

Tags: clojure

I'm pretty new to clojure, have the below dataset which I have parsed in from an xml document and displayed in an excel file:

```
({:Total 28, :p3percent 89.28571428571429, :p2percent 0.0, :p1percent 10.71428571428571, :APP "A", :p1 3, :p2 0, :p3 25}
 {:Total 40, :p3percent 92.5, :p2percent 0.0, :p1percent 7.5, :APP "b", :p1 3, :p2 0, :p3 37} 
 {:Total 64, :p3percent 93.75, :p2percent 0.0, :p1percent 6.25, :APP "c", :p1 4, :p2 0, :p3 60} 
 {:Total 128, :p3percent 83.59375, :p2percent 12.5, :p1percent 3.90625, :APP "d", :p1 5, :p2 16, :p3 107}
 {:Total 6, :p3percent 83.33333333333333, :p2percent 16.66666666666667, :p1percent 0.0, :APP "e", :p1 0, :p2 1, :p3 5}
 {:Total 8, :p3percent 87.5, :p2percent 12.5, :p1percent 0.0, :APP "f", :p1 0, :p2 1, :p3 7})
```

I want to sum up/average the values for each key and create a new entry in the dataset, with APP key "Total" and then show all the summed/averaged values in the last row.  This can easily be done in excel but I obviously want to do it in clojure first.

I know how to get the sum of each key i.e. (apply + map( :p1 dataset)), but how do I create a function to iterate through the dataset and add the totals on as an extra row in the dataset?

Thanks

D

Answer (score 1):

Try [merge-with](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.2.0/clojure.core/merge-with) function. Check second example from the link.
I think it's what you want. This function will help you to create last "total" row. The only problem that you have  one field that is not number. So you can pass special function to `merge-with` that ignores strings.

Comment: Hi Thanks for replying, I stayed away from merge-with + because I also want to get the average as well as the sum for certain keys... I should really have mentioned that in original description, apologies.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to sum up/average the values for each key and create a new entry in the dataset, with APP key "Total" and then show all the summed/averaged values in the last row.

I believe the previous answers have misunderstood the question. If you want to create a new entry in your dataset which contains totals for some keys and averages for others, then my answer may help.

---

Start by defining `sum` and `avg` in terms of a collection of numbers. You can always improve the implementation of these functions later, so keep it simple for now.

```
(defn sum [coll] (reduce + coll))
;;(sum [1 2 3])
;;=> 6
(defn avg [coll] (/ (sum coll) (count coll)))
;;(avg [1 2 3])
;;=> 2
```

To avoid repeating yourself, define a function for reducing your dataset.

```
(defn dataset-keys [d] (reduce #(into %1 (keys %2)) #{} d))

(defn reduce-dataset
  [f val dataset]
  (reduce (fn [m k] (assoc m k (f (map k dataset))))
          val
          (dataset-keys dataset)))
```

`reduce-dataset` expects `val` to be a map and `dataset` to be a collection of maps, like your dataset.

Use `reduce-dataset` to define `totals` and `averages` in terms of `sum` and `avg`.

```
(defn totals [dataset] (reduce-dataset sum {:APP "Totals"} dataset))
(defn averages [dataset] (reduce-dataset avg {:APP "Averages"} dataset))
```

Since you want to the total of some keys in your dataset and the average of others, you'll need a way to select just those keys across the dataset.

```
(defn select-cols [dataset ks] (map #(select-keys % ks) dataset))
```

Now you have everything you need to calculate totals and averages selectively across your dataset.

```
(totals (select-cols your-dataset [:Total :p1 :p2 :p3]))
;;{:Total 274, :p2 18, :p3 241, :p1 15, :APP "Totals"}

(averages (select-cols your-dataset [:p1percent :p2percent :p3percent]))
;; {:p3percent 88.32713293650794, :p1percent 4.728422619047618, :p2percent 6.9444444444444455, :APP "Averages"}
```

You can combine the results with your original dataset using conj.

```
(conj dataset
      (totals (select-cols dataset [:Total :p1 :p2 :p3]))
      (averages (select-cols dataset [:p1percent :p2percent :p3percent])))
```

This adds two rows to the dataset, one for totals and one for averages. To add a single row, you can merge the results before conj'ing.

```
(conj dataset
      (merge (totals (select-cols dataset [:Total :p1 :p2 :p3]))
             (averages (select-cols dataset [:p1percent :p2percent :p3percent]))
             {:APP "Total/Avg"}))
```

In the case of conflicting keys, `merge` will always use the last value it sees, so in the example above, The value of `:APP` will be `"Total/Avg"` not `"Totals"` or `"Averages"`.

Answer (score 0):

if you are just asking about producing a map that contains the totals or averages of the corraponding keys `reduce` can do this nicely:

```
user> (pprint (reduce #(assoc %2 :Total (+ (:Total %2) (:Total %1))) 
                      {:Total 0} data))
{:p1 0,
 :p3 7,
 :p2percent 12.5,
 :p2 1,
 :p1percent 0.0,
 :APP "f",
 :p3percent 87.5,
 :Total 274}
nil
```

this can be wrapped up in a function which preserves the original key which is important so that you can take the sum of a key, and then take the average of it as well:

```
(defn sum-key [key new-key map] 
  (reduce #(assoc %2 new-key (+ (%1 new-key) (%2 key))) {new-key 0} data))
#'user/sum-key
user> (sum-key :Total :Total-sum data)
{:p1 0, :p3 7, :p2percent 12.5, :p2 1, :p1percent 0.0, :APP "f", :p3percent 87.5, :Total-sum 274, :Total 8}
```

and this function  can then be chained to summerize the keys you want

```
user> (->> data 
        (sum-key :Total :Total-sum) 
        (sum-key :p1 :p1-sum) 
        (sum-key :p2 :p2-sum))
{:p1 0, :p2-sum 18, 
 :p3 7, :p2percent 12.5, 
 :p2 1, :p1percent 0.0, 
 :APP "f", :p3percent 87.5, 
 :Total 8}
```

---

If you want running totals then use `reductions` instead.

Comment: @Arthur_Ulfeldt When does using reduce cause a problem by realizing the whole sequence? I'm asking that because I periodically see comments indicating why reduce shouldn't be used. tnx

Comment: reduce produces a result of reducing all the data you give it to a single value (hence it's name) so if you don't want it to realize the whole stream then use (take X data) instead. Reduce does not hold a reference to the head of the lazy sequence so it is safe to use it on datasets larger than ram.

Comment: I edited to better match the question, I had (i think) initially misunderstood.

Comment: it sounds like you need to preserve the original data in the map and add new keys containing the averages, sums, etc.